# logrotate not as expected

Tags: logrotate, systemd-timer

I have a logrotate service configured as below running on a user systemd timer.

The issue is that the target of the rotate is allowed to grow beyond the size specified in the logrotate.conf, and that it is not truncated.

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 stephen stephen  14M 2023-06-04 08:15 monitor-iotop.log.1
 -rw-r--r-- 1 stephen stephen  14M 2023-06-04 08:19 monitor-iotop.log
```

logrotate.conf

```
/mnt/ram/log/monitor-iotop.log {
    size 500K
    copytruncate
    rotate 1
    maxage 0
    missingok
    notifempty
    su stephen stephen
}
```

The timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Logrotate Timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
AccuracySec=1s
Unit=logrotate.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Logrotate Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate -s /tmp/logrotate.state /hd2/projects/test/top/logrotate.conf
```

And journalctl -u logrotate.service

```
2023-05-22T00:00:00.443993-0700 meer systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
2023-05-22T00:00:00.484405-0700 meer systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-22T00:00:00.513788-0700 meer systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
2023-05-23T00:00:00.478533-0700 meer systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
2023-05-23T00:00:00.506664-0700 meer systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-23T00:00:00.528445-0700 meer systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
2023-05-24T00:00:00.433292-0700 meer systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
2023-05-24T00:00:00.468817-0700 meer systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
2023-05-24T00:00:00.496690-0700 meer systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
```

Comment: Sometimes things are not what they seem to be... Did you make sure that both files are (mostly) identical (`diff`)? What is the output of `logrotate -f -v -s /tmp/logrotate.state /hd2/projects/test/top/logrotate.conf`

Comment: @HaukeLaging Ah. running `diff` shows the files are not text as I expect but `data`. Would that cause a problem? Anyway, I've modified the logging script to encode log statements as `ascii` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: `logrotate` might be unwilling to truncate a file if it (or the copy) does not end on a newline.

Comment: @StephenBoston Is your application opening the log file in append mode? If not, the truncate will create lots of null chars when the next log write is done at the old end-of-file. `ls -ls` will show the sparse nature of the log file.

Comment: @meuh It is opened for write in a python process and written with f-strings in a print statement. I'll try running in append. It could be that the attempt to rotate changes the source file. After looking into it more I think I should post another question if your suggestion doesn't help..